# How can I return the ws xyz position of the paint cursor in maya python?

Tags: python, maya, maya-api

I want to be able to focus the camera around the maya paint cursor while painting weights.
I need to grab the XYZ position of the cursor for me to do this, does anyone know how i can get this?

[image]

Comment: Specifically, it's Maya's Artisan Brush, and i'm looking for the 3D world space xyz.

Answer (score 1):

There is a discussion happened before like this in maya python group. Here is the [link](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/python_inside_maya/01GdWYRU4ok) and snippet down is what you looking for

```
from PySide import QtGui, QtCore

def print_mouse_position():

    point = QtGui.QCursor().pos()
    print "x: %s; y: %s" % (point.x(), point.y())

timer = QtCore.QTimer()
timer.setInterval(1000.0 / 25)  # Print 25 times per second
timer.timeout.connect(print_mouse_position)
timer.start()

#when ever you want to stop it uncomment below line
#timer.stop()
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll certainly give that a go! I was hoping for a way to retrieve feedback on Maya's native brush tool though. Wondered if there was a way of grabbing that :\

Comment: Ah, that's cool, but this is for returning the X and Y in the monitor's 2D space. I was hoping for a way to retrieve feedback on Maya's native brush tool's XYZ in 3D world space. :)

Comment: Oh in that case you can user draggerContext http://help.autodesk.com/cloudhelp/2017/CHS/Maya-Tech-Docs/Commands/draggerContext.html much easy